# tinymce 4 custom classes for users to use

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How can I add custom classes to tinymce 4? I want to have a select in where users can select a class to use on their text. I don't want to use the standard plugins like forecolor, because I want to give certain classes that my users can use.

Short example:

tinymce editor "select class" (button in the toolbar)

- Red
- Blue
- Green

my_custom_css.css

```
.red { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
.green { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `style_formats` configuration option for this. The TinyMCE documentation provides all information you need: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

The styles specified in that option will appear in a dropdown menu and can be applied as inline styles as well as classes. If you choose to apply classes to the selected elements, you'll probably like to include a custom stylesheet for the editor's content using the `content_css` option.

In your example, the respective part of the configuration would look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Red', inline: 'span', classes: 'red'},
        {title: 'Green', inline: 'span', classes: 'green'},
        {title: 'Blue', inline: 'span', classes: 'blue'}
    ],
    content_css: 'my_custom_css.css'
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! This works. I don't know how I have overlooked that part of the documentation.

Comment: @Callidior : what if i want to change first-letter font size how do i do that ?

Comment: @AnandDwivedi : Add a suitable class (e.g., 'initial') to your `style_formats` configuration and define it in your custom stylesheet like this: `.initial::first-letter { font-size: 2em; }` using the `::first-letter` pseudo-class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: @Callidior:  as you suggested for first-Letter its not applying style . but in same class if we define color then it works . or can you provide any fiddle or url which is using first letter big in tinyMCE